# Multi Module Project in Maven for Rich Client

Tags: java, swing, maven

I was wondering if anyone has any advice on how best to proceed with Maven and a multi-module Rich Client application (lets say its in Java Swing).

The requirements are that a certain core part of the application exists in some kind of core project. If you run this core project you still get to see something, lets say a bunch of different sub modules as tabs in a tabbed pane.

The Core is runnable and shows some Core GUI modules that are common to everyone.

[image]

One customer might be a Bus Operator and receive a configuration and see something like this

[image]

...whereas another customer might be a Pet Store that sees something like this:

[image]

What is the best Maven approach for this?

With respect to SuperPOMs what would be the best approach. As I understand you can have project inheritance and you can have project aggregation.

Would it be better to use inheritance and have all the modules inherit from the core project?

> ---> Core POM
>
> -------- Tarif Module POM (for transport company)
>
> -------- Routes Module POM (for transport company)
>
> -------- Cat Module POM (for pet store)
>
> -------- Dog Module POM (for pet store)

then all the sub projects would reference the super like thus :

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>CoreUI</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.huwag</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Some other external project would then build the JARs specific to the client. (this is where I am unsure... using inheritance, how can you create a configuration specific to one customer)

OR..... would it better to use project aggregation. In this sense I mean that each super POM would be an aggregation of modules specific to a client. Like this :

> ---> Transport company POM
>
> -------- Tarif Module POM
>
> -------- Routes Module POM
>
> ---> Pet Store POM
>
> -------- Cat Module POM
>
> -------- Dog Module POM
>
> ---> Core POM (would get referenced in the other two)

```
<project>
  <groupId>com.huwag</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyPetStore</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>DogComponent</module>
    <module>CatCopmonent</module>
    <module>Core</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

I am thinking the latter is the better option. For me I like that option because I can build in specific packaging better for the client. For example, one client might want his application packaged in webstart, and another might want it packaged in an applet.

If someone can help me with the Maven project structure that would be good.

Any other tips that people have experienced would be welcome. Did anyone use an OSGi option to glue the GUI sections together? How did the packaging work? etc.

Comment: You can try OSGI approach with help of [Eclipse RCP](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html) and [Equinox osgi container](http://www.vogella.com/articles/OSGi/article.html). In that case you can use some core modules for all clients and some specific plug-ins for each client, which will be loaded in skeleton GUI.

Comment: Along similar lines you could have Spring `@Component`s that are picked up by the application context if they're brought onto the classpath by your Maven configuration. We've been very successful with that approach.